# can a dataset contain a collection of other objects?

Tags: c#

in my code I have a function that returns a dataset but I can't change it, so I was hoping to:

1. Can a dataset contain another dataset?
2. Or can  a datatable contain a dataset thats contains data tables
3. Or can I take a genericlist and convert it to a datatable then add
   it to a data set?

Is any of this possible?

Comment: What did you find out when you tried? ;)

Comment: no - cant be done - the only way was to insert json - was wondering if anyone had another idea

Comment: Maybe if you tried describing your *actual* problem and attempted solutions, rather than an idea of how to solve an issue we know nothing about, we could possibly help. =)

Comment: Your third option is possible - to add additional `DataTable`s to your `DataSet`

Comment: Sounds bad. Lot of work. What did you try?

Comment: In the world of OOP there is a thing called 'Inheritance'. Study it and you will have your answers [Inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_(computer_science))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here are the answer to your questions

> Datasets store data in a disconnected cache. The structure of a dataset is similar to that of a relational database. it exposes a hierarchical object model of tables, rows, and columns. In addition, it contains constraints and relationships defined for the dataset.
>   You use datasets if you want to work with a set of tables and rows while disconnected from the data source.
>
> - The DataSet object is central to supporting disconnected
> - The DataSet is a memory-resident representation of data
> - The DataSet represents a complete set of data, including related tables, constraints, and relationships among the tables
> - An ADO.NET DataSet contains a collection of zero or more tables represented by DataTable objects

Here is the [MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bw9ksd6%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) for more information

Hope it will help

Answer (score 1):

1) No, in a dataset you can only put table and relationship, you can't put another dataset inside

2)No, Datatable can contains some column with a specific type, but is not a good way to use.

3) you can use this:

```
    public static class Extensions 
    {
            public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(this IList<T> data)
            {
                PropertyDescriptorCollection propriedades = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));
                DataTable dtTabela = new DataTable();
                for (int i = 0; i < propriedades.Count; i++)
                {
                    PropertyDescriptor prop = propriedades[i];
                    dtTabela.Columns.Add(prop.Name, prop.PropertyType);
                }
                object[] objValores = new object[propriedades.Count];
                foreach (T item in data)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < objValores.Length; i++)
                {
                objValores[i] = propriedades[i].GetValue(item);
            }
            dtTabela.Rows.Add(objValores);
        }
        return dtTabela;
    }
```